# Static page generator quazi CMS

Tags: cms, template, static-content

Are there some mainstream software packages that generate static pages?

Sort of like CMS, but without all the fluffy parts. I'm perfectly fine with editing pages using a text editor, but I would like to edit something more user friendly than HTML (markup, wiki text, etc...).

I'm just redoing my personal website, and the layers of layers of Drupal modules I need to install is just getting crazy.

Answer (score 1):

[Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/) works in exactly this way, generating the site as static pages when you hit publish, unless you set it up for dynamic publishing.

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) works in the reverse, it is always publishes dynamiclly unless you install a plugin like [wp-supercache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) which will serve cached pages, regenerating the cache as needed.

IMHO Wordpress is the better of the two, but do check carefully the features you use in drupal are available in Wordpress.

Comment: Drupal is pretty complicated with modules and modifying templates etc, i'd agree WordPress is the way to go, out of the box you have all you need for a blog and small CMS. As for features there's a plugin for just about everything.